# adempiere Upgrade 360 to 390

Tags: odoo, adempiere, idempiere

I need to upgrade my current version (adempiere 360) to 380 version.
Note : did development in current version

1. Added new screens
2. Added new java classes and changed existings
3. separate module

Please help me to do this upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Visit wiki.adempiere.net for help with your problem.

There is a great Migration Tool that will help you migrate your database to the latest version.  It will keep your customization work - as long as you have performed the customizations in other than the Dictionary entity type.

Specifically see http://wiki.adempiere.net/Upgrading_and_Migration for details.

Good luck!